# Plotly.js pie chart values format

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, plotly

I'm creating some pie charts with Plotly.js but I can't figure out how to set the value format. If my number is 19.231, I get 19.2. I want 19.2310, with 4 digit precision. My data and layout follow here:

```
var data = [{
    values: values,
    labels: labels,
    type: 'pie',
    marker: {
        colors: colors
    },
    textfont: {
        family: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
        size: 48,
        color: '#000'
    }
}];
var layout = {
    height: 1350,
    width: 1500,
    title: title,
    titlefont: {
        family: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
        size: 58,
        color: '#000'
    },
    legend: {
        x: 1.1,
        y: 0.5,
        size: 40,
        font: {
            family: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
            size: 48,
            color: '#000'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you add some of your values to have a minimal, verifiable example?

Comment: They are generated on the flow depending on the user input. Values are floats, plotly automatically round them to one digit after the comma.

Comment: if you try `var values = [1, 2, 4.6];` you get 13.2%, 26.3% and 60.5% instead of 13.1579%, 26.3158% and 60.5263%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do that directly in `Plotly` but you could add [`text`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#pie-text) values with your desired precision and set `textinfo` to `text`.

```js
var values = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
var sum = values.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
var digits = 4;
var rounded_values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
 rounded_values.push(Math.round(values[i]/sum * 100 * 10**digits) / 10**digits + '%');
}

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myPlot');
var data = [{
    values: values,
    type: 'pie',
    text: rounded_values,
 textinfo: 'text'
}];
Plotly.plot(myPlot, data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPlot"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, It's exactly what I was watching for.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the document find some rule

about  Advanced Hovertemplate it said

```
      data: [
        {
          type: "scatter",
          mode: "markers",
          x: x,
          y: y,
          text: t,
          marker: { size: s, sizeref: 4000, sizemode: "area" },
          transforms: [{ type: "groupby", groups: c }],
          hovertemplate:
            "<b>%{text}</b><br><br>" +
            "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:$,.0f}<br>" +
            "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:.0%}<br>" +
            "Number Employed: %{marker.size:,}" +
            "<extra></extra>"
        }
      ],
```

you can change here %{y:$,.0f}  0f to 4f .
like this

`hovertemplate: '%{y:$,.4f}',`

[Polt.ly JS document](https://plot.ly/javascript/hover-text-and-formatting/)